# How to catch exception info for the wrong url when to open it with selenium?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, exception

When you input `http://www.python.or/`  (intentionally use the wrong url) in firefox or other browsers, browser show something such as below:

The connection was reset

```
The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.    
The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer’s network connection.
If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the
```

Now let's do the same task with selenium.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
browser.get("http://www.python.or")
```

When you execute the above code in console,no error info,how to catch the exception such as firefox do with selenium?

[image]

Comment: But why would you run a test with the wrong url ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to try ***HTML requests***

First, get the requests from the *URL*:

`import requests
r = requests.get(your_url)`

Now you need to get the *status_code* from your request:

`print(r.status_code)`

*r.status_code* contains the http's error handler.

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) is a list of all the HTTP status codes

Try this and you'll know when something wrong happened (*ex* Error 404)